# Does changing data type decimal to float cause data loss?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, migration

I need to change a couple of fields in my database from:

```
:decimal, :precision => 8, :scale => 5
```

to:

```
:float
```

Does this migation result in data loss? The current data consists of integers between 0 and 999.

If this migration will impact these numbers already stored, how can I keep this data safe?

Setup: Ruby on Rails 3 running on Heroku (solution would need to work for both PostgreSQL and MySQL).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Integers between 0 and 999 will fit in either and the data won't be impacted.  If it is just integers - why not use `int`s?

Comment: It won't always be integers :)

Comment: so, as long as the current data literally fits inside the new data type, it'll be fine?

Comment: I would think so - you can always make a backup of your `development.db` just in case.  Migrate back from the change if things go wrong before restoring the backup.

Answer (score 1):

It will, if you ever need to do exact comparisons or floating point arithmetics on your numbers. Open up PostgreSQL and try this:

```
select floor(.8::float * 10.0::float); -- 8
select floor((.1::float + .7::float) * 10.0::float); -- 7
```

See this related question for the reason:

[Why do simple doubles like 1.82 end up being 1.819999999645634565360?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6006200/why-do-simple-doubles-like-1-82-end-up-being-1-819999999645634565360/6006212#6006212)

Comment: thanks for your answer - I'm more concerned with literally losing my numbers than having them slightly off their former value. If the field goes from that restrictive decimal to either float or a more expansive decimal (higher precision), I assume this means my data would remain safe?

Comment: Well, in this case yes, you're safe if you use an `ALTER TABLE` statement to modify the column's type. RoR might get the job done too, I've honestly no idea -- though if so, I'd place more trust in what I type than in a ruby-based SQL diff tool.