# How a Double.ToString() displays more chars that Double's precision?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, double, floating-point-precision

```
?(1.0-0.9-0.1)
-0.000000000000000027755575615628914

?((double)1.0-(double)0.9-(double)0.1)
-0.000000000000000027755575615628914

?((double)1.0-(double)0.9-(double)0.1).GetType()
{Name = "Double" FullName = "System.Double"}

?((double)1.0-(double)0.9-(double)0.1).ToString()
"-2,77555756156289E-17"
```

How a `Double.ToString()` displays more chars(32) that [double](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/678hzkk9%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)'s precision(15-16)?

I expect that `MyObject.ToString()` represents **just** *MyObject* and not `MyObject+SomeTrashFromComputer`

**Why**

```
?0.1
0.1
?0.2-0.1
0.1
?0.1-0.1
0.0
```

**BUT**

```
?1.0-0.9-0.1
-0.000000000000000027755575615628914
```

WHY

```
?1.0-0.1-0.9
0.0
```

**BUT**

```
?1.0-0.9-0.1
-0.000000000000000027755575615628914
```

Comment: Actually your ToString() result has fewer (significant) digits. And it certainly has less chars, about half.

Comment: You're confusing precision with significant figures ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significant_figures ) and you should know that decimal fractions like 0.1 cannot be represented exactly in binary. Have you tried using the Decimal data type?

Comment: Precision is not accuracy, if you don't want the "trash", don't use Double, or start rounding.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I think the "some trash from computer" is indicating that he isn't aware of floating point errors, rather than not knowing scientific notation.

Comment: @Servy - but it's not certain/clear, my main reason to close.

Comment: The leading zeros do not count towards the significant figures.

Comment: _How ... ToString() displays more chars(32)_ - it doesn't. Count them. It's 20 chars including the E17.

Comment: It's probably a duplicate for this one but it's hard to tell: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1662600

Answer (score 3):

> How a Double.ToString() displays more chars(32) that double's precision(15-16)?

It isn't displaying 32, it is displaying 17, leading zeros don't count. *Floating* point means it can keep track of changes in magnitude separately from changes in value.

> I expect that MyObject.ToString() represents just MyObject

It does, there may be a slight difference due to the mechanics of floating point numbers, but the true number is represented by the string precisely.

> not MyObject+SomeTrashFromComputer

There is no trash, there is floating point inaccuracy. It exists in decimal too, write down `1/3` as a decimal number exactly. You can't, it involves a repeating decimal place. Double's are stored in base 2, so even `0.1` creates a repeating "decimal".

Also note that you are getting two different representations because you are calling two different display methods. `ToString` has specific semantics, while your debugging window probably has different ones. Also look up scientific notation if you want to know what the `E` means.

Comment: I understand that "1/3" is not accurate, because of devision, but I can't undestand why "0.1" is innacurate!!!?

Comment: @serhio A Double works in binary, not decimal. Try writing 0.1(decimal) in binary. You will get 0.0001100110011001100110011001100110011...

Comment: why 0.2-0.1 gives ALWAYS EXACTLY 0.1??

Comment: why `1.0-0.1-0.9` is EXACTLY `0.0` but not `1.0-0.9-0.1`??

Comment: @serhio `0.2-0.1` doesn't give exactly `0.1`, it simply results in a number that is rounded to `0.1` when displayed to you because that's the closest approximation.  `why 1.0-0.1-0.9 is EXACTLY 0.0 but not 1.0-0.9-0.1?` The first one doesn't actually work out *exactly*, it simply rounds to the correct value "coincidentally".  Both expressions result in floating point errors.

Comment: @serhio: Remember that all decimals are fractions. 0.1 is really 1/10, 0.25 is really 25/100 which can be simplified to 1/4. Given 1/10 and based 2 digits, write out that number. You can't you get 0.000110011 and so on.

Answer (score 2):

Check this [System.Double](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.aspx)

> Remember that a floating-point number can only approximate a decimal number, and that the precision of a floating-point number determines how accurately that number approximates a decimal number. By default, a Double value contains 15 decimal digits of precision, although a maximum of 17 digits is maintained internally. The precision of a floating-point number has several consequences:
>
> Two floating-point numbers that appear equal for a particular precision might not compare equal because their least significant digits are different.
>
> A mathematical or comparison operation that uses a floating-point number might not yield the same result if a decimal number is used because the floating-point number might not exactly approximate the decimal number.
>
> A value might not roundtrip if a floating-point number is involved. A value is said to roundtrip if an operation converts an original floating-point number to another form, an inverse operation transforms the converted form back to a floating-point number, and the final floating-point number is equal to the original floating-point number. The roundtrip might fail because one or more least significant digits are lost or changed in a conversion.

Comment: Why "0.1" is not just "0.1" but "0.1000000000000000xyzrklsjdhf"?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're unclear on two aspects of a floating point number; the *precision* and the *range*.

The *precision* of a floating point representation is how closely it can approximate a given decimal. The precision of a `double` is 15-16 digits.

The *range* of a floating point representation is related to how large or small of a number can be approximated by that representation. The range of a `double` is +/-5.0e-324 to +/-1.7e308.

So in your case, the calculation is precise to exactly 16 characters, and after that is not, as would be expected.

[Some numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Representable_numbers.2C_conversion_and_rounding) that would seem simple are just not representable in standard floating point representation. If you require absolutely no deviation, you should use a different data type like `decimal`.